# java.lang.IllegalStateException:The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, performance, listview

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

1.My app is Navigation app using GPS location, marker will animate from source to destination according to user car drive, hence the highway details will get populated using RightsideDrawer listview in same activity, once the current location fetched: it automatically updates the nearby shop location in right side listview with its detail and update distance calculation using current location for all list items in listview(in RightNavigationSubViewAdapter -customadapter class).

2.Location updates for every 3000ms, CurrentLocationUpdateList is called for 3 sec once. while updating rightside drawer sublistview (when user is in driving) it occurs crash on some mobiles like Micromax TAB, Samsung Grand Prime and HTC 4.4.2. while driving, Only these mobiles occuring crash on very rare case, i need to fix it soon. kindly help me to resolve it.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
try {
mCurrentLocation = location;
Singleton.getInstance().mCurrentLocation = location;
final LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
if (isMapReady) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            CurrentLocationUpdateList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG_MSG, "Error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        checkAlertView();
        updateMarker(mCurrentLocation);
        updateCamera(position);
        updatePolyLine(position);
    }
});
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d(TAG_MSG, "Error", e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

3.Right Side Drawer Layout for sublistview, when rightside drawer is opened below functionality will do its UpdateRightSideOpenView work. i.e Singleton.getInstance().drawerOpenRightSubList = true.

```
public void CurrentLocationUpdateList {
if (Singleton.getInstance().drawerOpenRightSubList) { 
try {
new UpdateRightSideOpenView().execute();                         
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} 
else {
try {
    new UpdateRightSideSubView().execute();
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

4.Right side Subview func call, RightNavigationSubViewAdapter is used for open right drawer, RightNavigationViewAdapter is used for closed right drawer, 2 adapter for 2 listview, one is for drawer open view and another is for drawer closed view, hence openview will get extra data.

```
public class UpdateRightSideOpenView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
try {
subAdapter = new RightNavigationSubViewAdapter(mContext, wayPoints);
mListSub.setAdapter(subAdapter);
mListSub.requestLayout();
subAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

adapter = new RightNavigationViewAdapter(mContext, wayPoints);// load new data
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mList.requestLayout();
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}


public class UpdateRightSideSubView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
try {
/*mListSub.invalidateViews(); *///invalidate old
subAdapter = new RightNavigationSubViewAdapter(mContext, wayPoints);
mListSub.setAdapter(subAdapter);
subAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();          // call notifydatasetChanged
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use AsyncTasks if you always `return null;` in `doInBackground()`. Why you use them at all?

Comment: setAdapter and its notifyDatasetChanged have do its work in UI thread, so i included like this, previously i used runonUithread() method also, no use of it.     For example                                                                                                                                  subAdapter = new RightNavigationSubViewAdapter(mContext, wayPoints);
mListSub.setAdapter(subAdapter);
mListSub.requestLayout();
subAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: but still why you use AsyncTask? you don't do anything in the background at all.

Comment: ok fine, just need to call that function in runonUIthread, thats right know